# Проблемы с Denwer

Tags: denwer, php, сервер

Через ftp скачал с сервера файлы, для работы, через денвер закинул все, как положено, запускаю, выдает ошибки, проверяю ошибки натыкаюсь на одну и ту же строку

> `($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/Под папка сервера/ещё одна/header.php"(файлов много header просто пример));`

Помогите, что делать.

P.S. создается такое впечатление, что команда `DOCUMENT_ROOT` вообще не распознается.

Comment: > запускаю, выдает ошибки

Какие?

> закинул все как положено

Куда именно вы их закинули?

Comment: Warning: require(W:/home/localhost/www/incom/template/header.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\home\localhost\www\docs\index.php on line 5
W:\home\localhost\www\docs

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте лучше XAMPP (https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/index.html). Денвер не стоит откапывать.

Answer (score 0):

Не буду еще выпытывать про htaccess... Для начала, попробуйте так: в папке **home** создаете папку **site.loc**, в ней папку **www** и вот сюда закидываете все файлы своего сайта. Обязательно перезапускаете Denwer и в браузере набираете **http://site.loc**

Comment: меня тупо выкидывает в поисковик по умолчанию google.ru

Comment: Тогда протстой тест. Когда ставиться денвер, то создаются тестовые сайты. Если вы их не удалили, то попробуйте вбить http://test1.ru/

Comment: вбил, загрузилась страница "Это файл /home/test1.ru/www/index.html."

Comment: Тогда проблемы точно не в Denwer-e. Возможно, что в .htaccess прописаны какие-то правила, которые влияют на пути. Поковыряйте там.

Comment: require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/template/header.php"); правильно же строка написана или же там надо require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."../template/header.php");
хотя и так и так не работает. хээээййй народ подскажите плиииз.

Comment: Попробуйте в конец вашего названия поставить слэш, то есть вместо http://site.loc вбить http://site.loc/ , у меня всегда так в гугл перебрасывает если браузер гугл хром.

Comment: блин,да когда же наконец поймете - Денвер,это как курсы Попова,вроде и знаешь но "не работает".Удалите этот Денвер,и поставьте Xampp,если ручками не хотите ставить апач и мускул!